# Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider Unknown provider: TasksProvider <- Tasks <- IndexController

Tags: angularjs

I've seen a few posts similar to this one, however I think I implemented the dependencies correctly but I still seem to be getting the error. Here is the code.

IndexController:

```
/**
* IndexController

* @namespace task_list.layout.controllers
*/
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('task_list.layout.controllers')
    .controller('IndexController', IndexController);

  IndexController.$inject = ['$scope', 'Auth', 'Tasks', 'Snackbar'];

  /**
  * @namespace IndexController
  */
  function IndexController($scope, Auth, Tasks, Snackbar) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.isAuthenticated = Auth.isAuthenticated();
    vm.tasks = [];

    activate();

    /**
    * @name activate
    * @desc Actions to be performed when this controller is instantiated
    * @memberOf task_list.layout.controllers.IndexController
    */
    function activate() {
      Tasks.all().then(tasksSuccessFn, tasksErrorFn);

      $scope.$on('task.created', function (event, task) {
        vm.tasks.unshift(task);
      });

      $scope.$on('task.created.error', function () {
        vm.tasks.shift();
      });

      /**
      * @name tasksSuccessFn
      * @desc Update tasks array on view
      */
      function tasksSuccessFn(data, status, headers, config) {
        vm.tasks = data.data;
      }

      /**
      * @name tasksErrorFn
      * @desc Show snackbar with error
      */
      function tasksErrorFn(data, status, headers, config) {
        Snackbar.error(data.error);
      }
    }
  }
})();
```

Tasks

```
/**
* Tasks
* @namespace task_list.tasks.services
*/
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('task_list.tasks.services')
    .factory('Tasks', Tasks);

  Tasks.$inject = ['$http'];

  /**
  * @namespace Tasks
  * @returns {Factory}
  */
  function Tasks($http) {
    var Tasks = {
      all: all,
      create: create,
      // edit: edit,
      // delete: delete,
      get: get
    };

    return Tasks;

    ////////////////////

    /**
    * @name all
    * @desc Get all Tasks
    * @returns {Promise}
    * @memberOf task_list.tasks.services.Tasks
    */
    function all() {
      return $http.get('/api/v1/tasks/');
    }

    /**
    * @name create
    * @desc Create a new Task
    * @param {string} name The name of the new Task
    * @returns {Promise}
    * @memberOf task_list.tasks.services.Tasks
    */
    function create(name) {
      return $http.post('/api/v1/tasks/', {
        name: name
      });
    }

    /**
     * @name get
     * @desc Get the Tasks of a given user
     * @param {string} username The username to get Tasks for
     * @returns {Promise}
     * @memberOf task_list.tasks.services.Tasks
     */
    function get(username) {
      return $http.get('/api/v1/accounts/' + username + '/tasks/');
    }
  }
})();
```

Task_list.js

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('task_list', [
      'task_list.routes',
      'task_list.auth',
      'task_list.layout',
      'task_list.tasks',
      'task_list.config',
      'task_list.utils',
    ]);

  angular
    .module('task_list.routes', ['ngRoute']);

  angular
    .module('task_list.config', []);

  angular
    .module('task_list')
    .run(run);

  run.$inject = ['$http'];

  /**
  * @name run
  * @desc Update xsrf $http headers to align with Django's defaults
  */
  function run($http) {
    $http.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
    $http.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
  }
})();
```

I load of the modules and their subfolders (controllers,directives, services). Note that I'm minifying the files and loading each module in my app as such:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('task_list.layout', [
      'task_list.layout.controllers'
    ]);

  angular
    .module('task_list.layout.controllers', []);
})();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Here is the console log:

```
c98216751c41.js:2140 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: TasksProvider <- Tasks <- IndexController
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/unpr?p0=TasksProvider%20%3C-%20Tasks%20%3C-%20IndexController
    at http://127.0.0.1:9090/static/CACHE/js/c98216751c41.js:1507:8
    at http://127.0.0.1:9090/static/CACHE/js/c98216751c41.js:1721:7
    at Object.getService [as get] (http://127.0.0.1:9090/static/CACHE/js/c98216751c41.js:1737:122)
    at http://127.0.0.1:9090/static/CACHE/js/c98216751c41.js:1721:212
    at getService (http://127.0.0.1:9090/static/CACHE/js/c98216751c41.js:1737:122)
    at injectionArgs (http://127.0.0.1:9090/static/CACHE/js/c98216751c41.js:1740:58)
    at Object.instantiate (http://127.0.0.1:9090/static/CACHE/js/c98216751c41.js:1747:106)
    at $controller (http://127.0.0.1:9090/static/CACHE/js/c98216751c41.js:2000:20)
    at Object.link (http://127.0.0.1:9090/static/CACHE/js/c98216751c41.js:2681:377)
    at http://127.0.0.1:9090/static/CACHE/js/c98216751c41.js:1576:296 <div class="col-xs-12 ng-view ng-scope">
```

tasks.module.js

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('task_list.tasks', [
      'task_list.tasks.controllers',
      'task_list.tasks.directives',
      'task_list.tasks.services',
    ]);

  angular
    .module('task_list.tasks.controllers', []);

  angular
    .module('task_list.tasks.directives', ['ngDialog']);

  angular
    .module('task_list.tasks.services', []);
})();
```

Load order of js files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascripts/task_list.js' %}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascripts/task_list.config.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascripts/task_list.routes.js' %}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascripts/auth/auth.module.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascripts/auth/services/auth.service.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascripts/auth/controllers/register.controller.js' %}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascripts/tasks/tasks.module.js' %}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascripts/auth/controllers/login.controller.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascripts/layout/layout.module.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascripts/layout/controllers/navbar.controller.js' %}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascripts/tasks/directives/tasks.directive.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascripts/tasks/controllers/tasks.controller.js' %}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascripts/utils/utils.module.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascripts/utils/services/snackbar.service.js' %}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascripts/layout/controllers/index.controller.js' %}"></script>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does this have to do with python (or django)?

Comment: It seems like your Tasks service is not registered. Can your put a console log or something to see if your service is instantiated or if it has been loaded ? you can check out the final bundle file to see if it included. It throws this error because the indexController cannot find the Tasks service

Comment: @mgilson Its just that the project I'm working on is in django and I integrated angular as my view, but to your point it doesn't.

Comment: @AminMeyghani I've added the log. I do register the service. I register it in my tasks.module.js

Comment: try injecting your `services` module into your `controllers` module, i.e.  `angular.module('task_list.tasks.controllers', ['task_list.tasks.services']);`

Comment: @Claies Thanks, I tried that and same error. I had also tried passing the the `tasks.services` in the `layout.controllers` where I am instantiating and passing in my Tasks provider as such 
`angular
    .module('task_list.layout', [
      'task_list.layout.controllers'
    ]);

  angular
    .module('task_list.layout.controllers', ['task_list.tasks.services']);` But same error keeps coming up. I can't seem to find out what I'm missing.

Comment: what order are you loading your scripts in your HTML file?  you have to load the services before the other modules that use the services.

Comment: @Claies I've added the scripts loading order in my original question. I'm pretty sure I ordered it in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my issue. I actually wasn't loading the tasks_list.service script in my html file. I was able to better see that when I edited my original comments. I somehow missed it. Thanks for the responses which helped me isolate it.

Missing code in my html file:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascripts/tasks/services/tasks.service.js' %}"></script>`